# GRPC Heartbeat Thread Failures

Tags: c++, grpc

I have a GRPC Heartbeat function implemented in a class using the example at the link below

https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/async/

Here is my Heartbeat code

```
void GrpcClient::Heartbeat() { // statically attach a Worker server to Master-Worker Client Thread.


    while (1) {

        CompletionQueue cq;
        Ping request;
        {
            AsyncClientHearbeatCall *call = new AsyncClientHearbeatCall();
            // Prep the Async call - Core dump at this point when started as a separate thread from the main.
            call->response_reader = worker_stub->PrepareAsyncheartbeat(&call->context, request, &cq);
            // Set a Deadline for the Client Context. If Hearbeat not received in 1 seconds. Assume server is dead
            call->context.set_deadline( std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            // StartCall initiates the RPC call
            call->response_reader->StartCall();
            // Wait for Response
            call->response_reader->Finish(&call->reply, &call->status, (void *)call);
             
        }

            // Question? Can I reuse the "Call" declared above.
            // The Hello world example redeclared call. So, following that approach

            void *got_tag;
            bool ok = false;
            // check whether data is in the completion queue.
            GPR_ASSERT(cq.Next(&got_tag, &ok));
            // Verify that the request was completed successfully. Note that "ok"
            // corresponds solely to the request for updates introduced by Finish().
            GPR_ASSERT(ok);
            // The tag in this example is the memory location of the call object
            AsyncClientCall *call = static_cast<AsyncClientCall *>(got_tag);

            if (call->status.ok()) {
                health_status = "Good";
                //std::cout << "Worker:" << this->ip_address << " Health is Good" << std::endl;
            }   
            else {
                health_status = "Bad";
                std::cout << "Worker:" << this->ip_address << " Health is Bad" << std::endl;
            }
            delete call;  // Free object    
            sleep (2);
    }
            
}
```

when I run this as a thread.

```
    GrpcClient grpc_client(ip);
    //std::thread heartbeatthrd(&GrpcClient::Heartbeat, &grpc_client); 
    //heartbeatthrd.detach();
```

It works for a while and then it crashes...using gdb shows the below output

[image: (gdb) backtrace #0 0x00005555557e8d2e in grpc_call_unref () #1 0x0000555555688b79 in grpc::ClientContext::~ClientContext() () #2 0x00005555555f37f2 in AsyncClientCall::~AsyncClientCall() () #3 0x00005555555ef5e1 in GrpcClient::Heartbeat() () #4 0x000055555560577e in void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (GrpcClient::)(), GrpcClient>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (GrpcClient::&&)(), GrpcClient&&) () #5 0x00005555555fee70 in std::__invoke_result<void (GrpcClient::)(), GrpcClient>::type std::__invoke<void (GrpcClient::)(), GrpcClient>(void (GrpcClient::&&)(), GrpcClient&&) () #6 0x0000555555632aad in decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (GrpcClient::)(), GrpcClient> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) () #7 0x000055555562e500 in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (GrpcClient::)(), GrpcClient> >::operator()() () #8 0x00005555556291fe in std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (GrpcClient::)(), GrpcClient> > >::_M_run() () #9 0x00007ffff5e656df in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 #10 0x00007ffff77826db in start_thread (arg=0x7fffb5ffb700) at pthread_create.c:463 #11 0x00007ffff552261f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95]

Comment: I am wondering whether I have handled the thread correctly? I want another pair of eyes to confirm if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: Consider running asan and tsan builds to help you debug.

Comment: Both `tsan` and `Helgrind` are so full of -- presumably -- false positives, it's difficult to understand how you can get useful output.